# Jest snapshot is redundant

Tags: jestjs, ui-testing

I am writing snapshot tests using Jest for a node.js and React app and have installed snapshot-tools extension in VS code.

Some of my tests are displaying this warning in the editor:

> [snapshot-tools] The snapshot is redunant

(Presumably it is supposed to say redundant)

**What does this warning mean? I am wondering how I can fix it.**

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, so I took a look at the "snapshot-tools" code. It marks a snapshot section as redundant, if it doesn't see a corresponding test in the test file that has a matching name and that calls "expect().toMatchSnapshot()" or something similar.

The problem is (as it says on the "Limitations" section of the plugin's marketplace page), it does a static analysis of the test file to find those tests that use snapshots. And the static analysis cannot detect tests that have dynamically generated names, or that don't directly call "expect().toMatchSnapshot()" in the test's body.

For example, I was getting false positive "redundant" warnings, because I had some tests that were doing "expect().toMatchSnapshot()" in their "afterEach()" function, rather than directly in the test body.

Answer (score 0):

This could indicate that the snapshot is no longer linked to a valid test - have you changed your describe/it strings without updating the snapshots? Try running the tests with `-- -u` appended (eg: `npm test -- -u`). If that doesn't work, have a look at your snapshots file and compare the titles to your test descriptions.